# Is there any straight-function in Python to obtain a vector of a certain attribute from a vector of objects?

Tags: python, class, attributes

I am new to Python programming and I have not found a suitable straight way to do the following task:

I have a class named "INDIVIDUAL" that has two attributes, "Genome" and "Fitness". And I have a vector "Population" that stores hundreds of objects from the class "INDIVIDUAL".
I want to obtain a new vector "ANS" that stores all of the attributes "Genome" from all the objects from the vector "Population".
I know that it can be done by implementing loops, but I wonder if there is a straight way (An easy way, maybe just in 1 line, with no loops) to do it. My code is placed below:

```py
class INDIVIDUAL:
    def __init__(self, Genome, Fitness):
        self.Genome=Genome
        self.Fitness=Fitness

NInd=500
Population=[None]*NInd
for i in range(NInd):
    Population[i]=INDIVIDUAL(random.choices([0,1],k=10),random.choices([0,1],k=1))

ANS=**Help!**
```

Which is that "Straight way" to do my task?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please format your code correctly and make sure everything is readable before you post the question.

Comment: Your question mentions custom classes, but the code doesn't involve anything but np.ndarray objects, in one instance, oddly, using a list

Comment: Fixed! I just added my original code. @juanpa.arrivillaga

Comment: What do you mean by "straight"?

Comment: A quick way to do it, without loops in it.

Comment: The correct what is to just use `.append` in a loop.Thats the *idiomatic* way at least. Don't do `Population=[None]*NInd` just use `population = []`

Comment: Thanks for your comment  @juanpa.arrivillaga, the little problem is that I get an error "IndexError: list assignment index out of range" using your suggestion.

Comment: @BrianNiñoParra there is *no reason* to index anything. Just for `for _ in range(NInd):population.append(INDIVIDUAL(random.choices([0,1],k=10),random.choices([0,1],k=1)))`

Answer (score 1):

If you're still looking for a *pythonic* way, then I'd suggest to use a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3.8/tutorial/datastructures.html?#list-comprehensions):

```
NInd = 500
Population = [
    INDIVIDUAL(random.choices([0, 1], k=10), random.choices([0,1], k=1))
    for _ in range(NInd)
]
```

PS: If you're new to Python then take a look at [PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) to pick up best practice from the start.